# Can powered speakers actually send any Power/audio OUT of the input port?

Tags: pcb, audio

Thanks in advance for reading .So is there any chance that **reverse current is sent back** by old speakers,from speakers power adapter (**which fell down few times on ground**) to motherboard's green audio port and affecting/damaging the system.

Comment: Turn it off/unplug it and and turn the volume control back and forth over and over again. Connect and try again.

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially zero chance of that happening. It is unlikely that sending a line-level audio signal INTO the green output connector will actually "damage" anything. And it is equally unlikely that powered speakers can actually send any audio OUT of the input port.

You could clean the volume control by the usual methods (special aerosol spray for cleaning pots and switches).  Or you could replace those old plastic things with some modern speakers that will blow those away.